# Remove empty space from eclipse toolbar

Tags: android, eclipse, toolbar

I've looked into some questions but nothing seems to help.
I downloaded the new version of android ADT to keep up with the new google play services updates but encountered this annoying issue of eclipse JUNO.

See image please: [Right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IagBc.jpg)

Is there a solution for this?
Also is this version slow for everyone or just me? I am not sure because my computer have gotten a little slower lately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting the perspective (Window -> Reset Perspective) or maybe customizing it, if reset doesn't work (Window -> Customize Perspective). It hasn't been noticeably slower for me. Perhaps you should also consider [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) if Eclipse isn't cutting it for you.

Comment: I did and looks like there's missing items, I try to set them visible but I get a notice saying: " "XML Grammar Usage" cannot be made visible because it is in the unavailable "null" command group. Would you like to switch to the Command Group Availability tab? "